# Call simple action before login

Tags: java, struts2, url-rewriting, spring-security, appfuse

I'm working with Appfuse - Spring security,Struts and urlrewrite and I'm trying to call an action before login the app (I forgot my password functionality).

The problem is I can only access the action when the user is logged. The action is being redirected to login page.

I added the pattern `<http pattern="/resetPassword/**" security="none"/>` to security.xml

and the following rule in urlrewrite.xml

```
<rule>
    <from>/resetPassword</from>
    <to>/resetPassword</to>
</rule>
```

my security.xml

```
    <http pattern="/images/**" security="none"/>
<http pattern="/styles/**" security="none"/>
<http pattern="/scripts/**" security="none"/>
<http pattern="/assets/**" security="none"/>
<http pattern="/resetPassword/**" security="none"/>

<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/passwordHint*" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/signup*" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/saveSignup*" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**/*.action*" access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER"/>
    <form-login login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true" login-processing-url="/j_security_check" always-use-default-target = "true"/>
    <remember-me user-service-ref="userDao" key="e37f4b31-0c45-11dd-bd0b-0800200c9a66"/>
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDao">
        <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder">
        </password-encoder>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<!-- Override the default password-encoder (BCrypt) by uncommenting the following and changing the class -->
<!-- <bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder"/> -->

<global-method-security>
    <protect-pointcut expression="execution(* *..service.UserManager.getUsers(..))" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
    <protect-pointcut expression="execution(* *..service.UserManager.removeUser(..))" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
</global-method-security>
```

What could I be missing ?

Comment: The rule is obsolete.

Comment: Post whole security configuration.

Comment: What happens when you go to http://localhost:8080/resetPassword? If you comment out the filter-mapping for rewriteFilter (or securityFilter) from your web.xml, what happens?

Comment: Hi Matt, same result with no rewriteFilter but commenting out the securityFilter I can access the action but login stop working.

Comment: What url exactly are you hitting? It is probably intercepted by `/**/*.action*` and not `/resetPassword/**`.